# CamlQuery Retrieve Folder and files from specific folder

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml

Hi I'm working with sharepoint designer 2013 and I have this structure for document library webpart:

```
Folder1 
  SubFolder1 
    SubFile1.txt SubFile2.txt 
  File1.txt
```

I managed to target the Folder1, but it displays everything, SubFolder1, Subfile1.txt, Subfile2.txt and File1.txt at the same level. But what I want is SubFolder1 and File1.txt. And then if we click on SubFolder1 we have the files inside.
Something like this [image]

what I did :

```
<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/><Value Type="Text">pathOfFolder1</Value></Contains></Where></Query>
```

I set the scope to recursiveAll, and I tried also "All" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The example below for your reference:

```
<style>
    input[type=button] {
        background: #ccc;
        border: 0 none;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        font-size: small;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .dupHier img {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .dupHier a {
        position: relative;
        top: -2px;
    }

    .dupHier {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>

<!--To Populate Libraries-->
<select id="drpSelectSourceLibrary"></select>

<!--To Populate Levels on click-->
<input class="getLevels" name="getLevels" type="button" value="Get Levels" onclick="return false;" />

<!--To Populate Hidden Levels-->
<div class="genHier"></div>

<hr />

<!--To Populate Hierarchy Visible on page-->
<div class="dupHenHier"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Site Context URL
    var spctx = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;

    //Array to Store all the objects
    var hm = [];

    //Object involving File/Folder name, path, level in hierarchy, whether it is file or folder
    function hierMaker(name, path, level, isFile) {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.level = level;
        this.isFile = isFile;
    }

    var virtualLevel = 0;
    var boolVirtual = true;
    var maxLevel = 0;
    function getLevels() {

        //Reset global variables
        hm.length = 0;
        virtualLevel = 0;
        boolVirtual = true;
        maxLevel = 0;
        tctr = 1;
        $('.genHier').html("");
        $('.dupHenHier').html("");

        //Main code below
        var appWebUrl = spctx;
        var listName = $("#drpSelectSourceLibrary option:selected").text();
        var certURL = appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$expand=Folder,File&$select=ID,Title,FileLeafRef,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl,File/ServerRelativeUrl";
        $.ajax({
            url: certURL,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                getFolderSchema(data.d.results);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });

        function getFolderSchema(data) {
            maxLevel = 0;
            dLength = data.length;
            if (dLength >= 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dLength; i++) {
                    if (boolVirtual) {

                        if (data[i].Folder.ServerRelativeUrl) {
                            virtualLevel = data[i].Folder.ServerRelativeUrl.split('/').length;
                            boolVirtual = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            virtualLevel = data[i].File.ServerRelativeUrl.split('/').length;
                            boolVirtual = false;
                        }
                    }
                    var isFile = false;
                    var path = "";
                    var level = 0;
                    if (data[i].Folder.ServerRelativeUrl) {
                        //It is folder
                        isFile = false;
                        path = data[i].Folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        level = data[i].Folder.ServerRelativeUrl.split('/').length - virtualLevel;
                    }
                    else {
                        //It is file
                        isFile = true;
                        path = data[i].File.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        level = data[i].File.ServerRelativeUrl.split('/').length - virtualLevel;
                    }
                    var tmpDiv = "<div class='subHier' isFile='" + isFile + "' level='" + level + "' path='" + path + "'><a  href='" + path + "' target='_blank'>" + data[i].FileLeafRef + "</a></div>";
                    $(".genHier").append(tmpDiv);
                    maxLevel++;

                    var hmsc = new hierMaker(data[i].FileLeafRef, path, level, isFile);
                    hm.push(hmsc);
                }
                providePaddding();
            }

        }

    }


    var d = 1;
    function providePaddding() {
        var kickCtr = 0;
        var hmlength = hm.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < hmlength; j++) {
            //Creation of level 0 elements
            if (hm[j].level == 0) {
                var tmpDiv = "";
                if (hm[j].isFile) {
                    tmpDiv = "<div class='dupHier' isFile='" + hm[j].isFile + "' level='" + hm[j].level + "' path='" + hm[j].path + "'><img src='" + file + "' /><a  href='" + hm[j].path + "' target='_blank'>" + hm[j].name + "</a></div>";
                }
                else {
                    tmpDiv = "<div class='dupHier' isFile='" + hm[j].isFile + "' level='" + hm[j].level + "' path='" + hm[j].path + "'><img src='" + folder + "' /><a  href='" + hm[j].path + "' target='_blank'>" + hm[j].name + "</a></div>";
                }

                kickCtr++;
                $('.dupHenHier').append(tmpDiv);
            }
        }

        call();

    }


    var tctr = 1;
    var folder = spctx + "/Style Library/folder.JPG";
    var file = spctx + "/Style Library/file.JPG";
    function call() {
        $('.dupHier').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('isDone')) {
                //continue;
            }
            else {
                for (var j = 0; j < hm.length; j++) {
                    if (hm[j].level == tctr) {
                        var str = hm[j].path + "";
                        var ts = $(this).attr('path');
                        var tmpDiv = "";
                        if (str.indexOf(ts) > -1) {

                            if (hm[j].isFile) {
                                tmpDiv = "<div class='dupHier' isFile='" + hm[j].isFile + "' level='" + hm[j].level + "' path='" + hm[j].path + "'><img src='" + file + "'/><a  href='" + hm[j].path + "' target='_blank'>" + hm[j].name + "</a></div>";
                            }
                            else {
                                tmpDiv = "<div class='dupHier' isFile='" + hm[j].isFile + "' level='" + hm[j].level + "' path='" + hm[j].path + "'><img src='" + folder + "'/><a  href='" + hm[j].path + "' target='_blank'>" + hm[j].name + "</a></div>";
                            }

                            $(this).append(tmpDiv);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $(this).attr('isDone', true);
        });

        tctr++;
        if (tctr < 10)
            call();
        //Provide padding as per level, level * 10px
        $('.dupHier').each(function () {
            var tmpPad = $(this).attr('level') * 10 + "px";
            $(this).css({ "padding-left": tmpPad });
        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.getLevels').click(function () {
            getLevels();
        });

        $('.genHier').hide();
    });

    //Population of libraries
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadDocLibraries, "SP.js");
    function loadDocLibraries() {       
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(web);
        listColl = web.get_lists();
        clientContext.load(listColl);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onLibSuccess, onLibfail);

    }
    function onLibSuccess() {
        var listEnumerator = listColl.getEnumerator();
        var Lib = "";
        $('#drpSelectSourceLibrary').empty();
        $("#drpSelectSourceLibrary").prepend('<option value="Select" selected="selected">Select Documents Library</option>');


        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
            var value = list.get_hidden();
            //console.log(value);
            if (list.get_baseTemplate() == '101') {
                if (value == false) {

                    var x = document.getElementById("drpSelectSourceLibrary");
                    var option = document.createElement("option");

                    var filename = list.get_title();

                    option.text = filename;
                    x.add(option);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    function onLibfail() {
        console.log(arguments[1].get_message());
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Refer to: http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/unlimited-files-folders-hierarchy-sharepoint-online-using-rest-api/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried this and it's not working .. well almost, it displays SubFolder1 and File1.txt, but when I click in the SubFolder1, there's no files...

Comment: if you click "SubFolder1", you need do query again and the folderServerRelativeUrl  set "/sites/team/Shared Documents/Folder1/SubFolder1"

Comment: Well it's not practical if I have to always do a query for a subfolder that user create.. Are there any possibilities to filter with the file's id for example, then if the files' id in the first level are the same than in the sub folder, then we remove it?

Comment: I modify the reply as above, add the code into a script editor web part in the web part page.